# ARC weird deallocation behavior in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, exc-bad-access

I've had this behavior happen to me twice recently and I was wondering what the root cause of the problem is (aka how do I make sure this never happens so I don't have to waste a ton of time fixing it).

When I allocate something inside of a tableview cell that is slated for reuse, once another cell is loaded and the table reloads, sometimes that object is deallocated.

Example:

```
SubHolder *dataStorage;

- (void) initializeLicenseTable
    {
        LicenseCell *sampleLicense = [LicenseCell new];
        self.licenseData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:sampleLicense, nil];
        nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"LicenseCell" bundle:nil];

    if (dataStorage == nil)
    {
        dataStorage = [SubHolder new];
        dataStorage.owner = self;
        [dataStorage addStorageLocation];
    }
} //cellForRowAtIndexPath and stuff
```

This code doesn't work without the if statement (it causes a dataStorage to become a zombie)

What causes this behavior? It seems like testing if dataStorage is nil and only then allocating it is the opposite of what should fix a zombie problem.

**-EDIT-**

If this behavior is caused by sharing of the variables, how can I make it so that each time an instance of this object is created it makes its own data storage object? Each table has its own information, which is not shared with other tables.

Comment: is dataStorage a global variable?

Comment: It's 'global' in the context of the file it's in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `dataStorage` is a global variable (visible in the file scope of your class), it will be shared by all the instances of your class.

Now, if a second instance of your class is initialized and you don't check for

```
if (dataStorage == nil)
```

then your global object will be overwritten and thus at some point deallocated through ARC. If some other object had stored its value somewhere, it will try to access the old object and you get the zombie access.

EDIT:

if each object needs its own `dataStorage`, you will simply need to declare

```
SubHolder *dataStorage;
```

in your `interface` declaration, or a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SubHolder *dataStorage;
```

Comment: Interesting... so even if I don't call it static, the same memory location is used by every instance of the class if it's a global variable?

Comment: Well I tested it and this is definitely the case. What can I do to fix this? Each class should have its own instance of this variable.

Comment: yes, that is a global variable; `static` only means that the variable cannot be accessed from a different compilation unit (kind of private global).

Comment: you should declare that variable as a property to the class... please, see my edit.

Comment: Am I incorrect in feeling like that's not how things normally behave in other programming languages?

Comment: What exactly is not like things behave? maybe I misread you: "Each class should have its own instance of this variable"; could you elaborate more on this? I kindof assumed you meant "each object", hence my suggestion to make a property... on the other hand I cannot quite understand what you want to do...

Comment: Non-static variables sharing memory locations across multiple instances of classes. Also, I'll edit my question

Comment: `static` in C/C++/Objective-C has different meanings depending on where it is used: at the file scope or inside of a function; `static` within a function, makes the variable shared (global); at file scope, a variable is always global, static affects its visibility at linking time. This is C, not all programming languages are like this, so in a sense you are right...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just creating new cells all the time instead of reusing them.

You should re-use cells like this:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
if(cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:aStyle reuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
}
```

Comment: I do that in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. The method shown is for initialization.